# token bucket's implementation

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, networking, token

I'm trying to use the token bucket algorithm in my networking application in order to control the rate of data I want to send.

Does anyone here have an implementation of this algorithm in C language?

Otherwise, do you have any helpful resources where I could find the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged "c++" , I would recommend you to try it with using timers in boost asio.

Answer (score 1):

qLibc implements Tocket-Bucket in C.
You can also set initial burst rate and maximum tokens along with the refill rate.
It's much accurate than simple timer approach and gives more even distribution.

I'm one of the contributors. Check it out => [qLibc](https://github.com/wolkykim/qlibc)